# How can I stub a method on a object that is created at runtime

Tags: typescript, sinon, soap-client

I am trying to stub a method on a object with sinon that seems to only exist at runtime.

`const client = await createClientAsync(VatService.endpoint, { request: axiosIns }); const result = await client.checkVatAsync(args);`

With sinon.js I can stub the createClientAsync function of the "soap" package using:

`const createClientStub = this.sandbox.stub(soap, "createClientAsync").resolves();`

I also want to stub the checkVatAsync method of the client object. However this property does not exist on the client object type, it is created at runtime. The following fails:

`const checkVatStub = this.sandbox.stub(createClientStub, "checkVatAsync").resolves();`

and returns TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property checkVatAsync.

Comment: Is there a way to stub this method that is only created at runtime?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example